# Getting "unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'"every time I enter the terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, macos

I am running the latest version of OSX but this error has been occurring before multiple updates, I am not sure what really causes it, everytime I enter the terminal I get the following:

> Last login: Fri Apr  1 10:32:13 on ttys000
> -bash: eval: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
> -bash: eval: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file
>
> The default interactive shell is now zsh. To update your account to
> use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`. For more details, please visit
> https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.

My concern is the following two lines specifically:

> -bash: eval: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
> -bash: eval: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file

As I said before, I can't really remember when it happened or what triggered it, but it wasn't like this originally. I couldn't find anything online and otherwise the terminal seem to be working normally I just ignore this and write any command I want but I am not sure if it is causing any errors I am not aware of.

Edit:

Running the command `cat ~/.bashrc` shows the following :
`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: You have something wrong in (probably) your `.bashrc` file, but nobody can tell you what without seeing it. You can [edit] your post.

Comment: It is in some of your bash scripts that are executed at start of bash. Check the file. Add a `echo position 1` (and so on, to try to figure out where the problem is. Then you may figure out, or just ask here. To me it seems a copy/paste error, where a string is unterminated.

Comment: I edited my post to show my `.bashrc` file

Comment: Your screenshot shows `~/.bashrc.` (i.e. with a trailing `.` character), not `~/.bashrc` -- `.bashrc.` is not used by bash.  `.bashrc` (without trailing dot) is.    You need to examine that file.  And add the output of `cat ~/.bashrc` to your question if that doesn't make the answer obvious.   BTW, [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/bash.bashrc` file? If so, could you post the output of `cat`ting that as well?

Comment: @frabjous I don't!

Comment: OK, `~/.bashrc` looks fine (and it doesn't even have a line 4 or 5).  Next files to check are `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.bash_login`, then ~/.profile, then any files/dirs in `/etc/` starting with bash, and `/etc/profile`.    For an explanation of which files are used, run `man bash` and read the section headed "INVOCATION" (which is near the top of the man page), and the section "FILES" (which is near the end of the man page).

Comment: `~/.bash_profile` seems fine, `~/.bash_login` is empty, `~/.profile` has some comments on these lines so it is fine, I will check the rest thank you!